# How to center conent using React bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap, centering

I'm trying to do the infamous center operation both vertical and horizontal and have sorta succeeded in doing so.

I'm trying to render a simple react component on my page that will show a 404 message. I want this message to be centered. The way I managed to do this some whitespace is leftover resulting in vertical scroll bars showing up. Ofc I could get rid of them using something like overflow-hidden, but surely there must be a way to center this message perfectly just using a better structure or certain bootstrap classes.

Here is my component:

```
const NotFoundPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <NavbarComp />
            <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-center min-vh-100">
                <div>
                    <h3 className="m-4">
                        <Badge variant="primary">404</Badge> Page not found...
                    </h3>

                    <Link to="/">
                        <Button variant="secondary">Go to main page</Button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

In the end, I don't care that the scrollbars appear but it bothers me that this positional issue keeps occurring for me in some form or another and I wanna learn to put an end to this :)

Answer (score 0):

You have already figured out how to center your "Not Found" message. What's messing it up for you is the `Navbar`, which you can test by taking it out. You will notice that the scroll bars disappear.

This class `min-vh-100` gives the flex box below the Navbar the height of 100% of the viewport, which avoids adding any scrolls bars. The issue is that Navbar barges in and throw the page off blalance by attaching itself to the top. So the amount of srolling is exactly the height of the `Navbar` and since it's empty, there is very little scrolling.

An intutitive solution is to put your Navbar INSIDE the flex box. But that won't work in your case, because of how your flex box adjusts items. So I will give you a simpler solution, which should be viewed as more of a work-around.

Bootstrap does not come with classes such as `min-vh-95` or `min-vh-80`, but luckily they are super easy to create. You can add this class to your custom CSS:

```
.not-found-container {
  min-height: 95vh !important;
}
```

(*or you could just stick to the naming convention and name it `min-vh-95` for example*)
And then change the flex box classes from:

```
<div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-center min-vh-100">
```

to

```
<div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-center not-found-container">
```

Here is a Sandbox to illustrate the idea: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-sanne-e3m9w?file=/src/App.js

Obviously the `min-height` value would need to be adjusted based on the height if your Navbar.